# Create test/train split based on two groups with Pandas Scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas dataframe: `comb`
the number of `ENROLLED_Response` entries is quite small, so just random sampling of the entire DataFrame may lose too much of the enrolled data.

the solution is to take a 75% sample of all the entries where `ENROLLED_Response == True`
and then to take a 70% sample of all the entries where `ENROLLED_Response == False`

So I should end up with a column `is_train` with `true`/`false` on the DataFrame

so I usually use something like:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

#split the dataset for train and test
comb['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(comb)) <= .75
train, test = comb[comb['is_train']==True],  comb[comb['is_train']==False]
```

Which is fine for most cases,but due to the low number of enrolled this approach tends to leave out too many of the 'enrolled' since there are so few. So what I need is something more like:

```
comb['is_train'] = train_test_split(comb['ENROLLED_Response']==True, Train_size = 0.75)
comb['is_train']= train_test_split(comb['ENROLLED_Response']==False, Train_size = 0.75)
```

which of course does not work. the concept is: 1st sample the enrolled and mark a random .75 of them  as train, then sample the non enrolled (everything else) and mark .75 of them as train, in the same new column (is_train) so that  then it can easily be used in Scikit_learn like:

```
train, test = comb[comb['is_train']==True],comb[comb['is_train']==False]
```

Can't figure out how to do it since the np array generated by random is with respect to the length of the whole DataFrame (among other issues...)

Answer (score 0):

Updated after comment:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

truePct = 0.75
falsePct = 0.70

comb = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "feat1": np.random.randint(low=1, high=4, size=20),
    "feat2": np.random.randint(low=1, high=4, size=20),
    "ENROLLED_Response": np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=20)==3
})

# Set train to False by default
comb['train'] = False

# Create two permutations for both classes
nTrue = comb[comb.ENROLLED_Response==True].shape[0]
nFalse = comb[comb.ENROLLED_Response==False].shape[0]
truePerm = np.random.permutation(nTrue)[:int(np.floor(truePct*nTrue)-1)]
falsePerm = np.random.permutation(nFalse)[:int(np.floor(falsePct*nFalse)-1)]

# Select the indices
trainTrueIndex = comb[comb.ENROLLED_Response==True].index[truePerm].values.tolist()
trainFalseIndex = comb[comb.ENROLLED_Response==False].index[falsePerm].values.tolist()

comb.loc[trainTrueIndex,'train'] = True
comb.loc[trainFalseIndex,'train'] = True

print comb
```

results in

```
   ENROLLED_Response  feat1  feat2  train
0              False      3      1  False
1              False      1      1  False
2              False      3      2  False
3              False      3      2  False
4              False      1      1   True
5              False      1      1   True
6              False      3      1   True
7               True      2      3   True
8              False      3      3  False
9               True      3      3   True
10             False      3      2   True
11             False      3      3   True
12             False      1      2   True
13             False      3      2   True
14             False      2      3  False
15             False      1      2   True
16             False      2      3   True
17              True      2      3  False
18              True      2      1  False
19             False      2      3   True
```

---

I am not fully convinced I interpreted your question correctly, but it seems you are dealing with a class imbalance in your `ENROLLED_Response` variable. To preserve that class imbalance in both train- and test-sets you may want to use a different Scikit-Learn Cross-Validation function: [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit)

This function *is a merge of StratifiedKFold and ShuffleSplit, which returns stratified randomized folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.*

Comment: I think you did interpret correctly, however I think my memory constraints prevent me from this method, I have about 350,000 rows... So I have been running into memory issues when invoking things like "shuffleSplit" , hence why I'm trying to figure out how to handle more directly..

Comment: Looks good, will have to wait a bit to mark done, need to test and leaving for the week (yea!) Thanks